# genetic programming fitness function

Tags: r, computational-geometry, coordinate-transformation, genetic-programming

I am trying to write a fitness function in genetic programming to enlarge the area occupied by the points inside the polygon. There are some points near the center of the polygon, I want to expand these points from the center till it is just inside the polygon.

I was using the difference between the area occupied by the points inside the polygon and the area of outside polygon and trying to minimize it in the fitness function. But I don't know how to use this to change the coordinates of the points and then recalculate the difference in area and do it iteratively. I have given how the input and output should look like.

Thanks in advance.

This is the code I have written so far.

```
require(rgp)
require(splancs)
require(grDevices)
functionSet1 <- functionSet("+", "*", "-", "/","^")
inputVariableSet1 <- inputVariableSet("x","y")
constantFactorySet1 <- constantFactorySet(function() rnorm(1))

outpolygon<-matrix(c(3.061188,2.517408,0.523754,-0.258800,0.981104,4.036885,
                     3.061188,4.069070,4.069070,2.695074,0.485581,-2.129055,
                     -2.653607,4.069070),nrow=7,byrow=F)
inpoints<-matrix(c(2.637644,-0.4456578,2.160003,0.8553066,1.501256,1.3137518,2.352020,-0.2643815,
                   1.254139,1.2241712,1.918191,0.6595725,1.453478,0.9153824,1.900110,1.0607272,
                   1.648038,0.6847361,2.194931,2.2842159),nrow=10,byrow=T)

plot(-10:10,xlim=c(-5,5),ylim=c(-5,5))
polygon(outpolygon[,1],outpolygon[,2])
points(inpoints[,1],inpoints[,2])

fitnessFunction1 <-  function(f){
  if(all(point.in.polygon(inpoints[,1],inpoints[,2],outpolygon[,1],outpolygon[,2])!=0)){
    rmse(areapl(inpoints[chull(inpoints[,1],inpoints[,2]),]),areapl(cbind(outpolygon[,1],outpolygon[,2])[chull(outpolygon[,1],outpolygon[,2]),]))
  }else{
    rmse(1000,0)
  }
}

gpResult1 <- geneticProgramming(functionSet=functionSet1,
                                inputVariables=inputVariableSet1,
                                constantSet=constantFactorySet1,
                                fitnessFunction=fitnessFunction1,    
                                stopCondition=makeTimeStopCondition(10))


best1 <- gpResult1$population[[which.min(sapply(gpResult1$population,
                                                fitnessFunction1))]]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you already defined a good fitness function - the difference between the area of the polygon and the area taken up by the (convex hull) of the points. Of course, you may want to have some sort of negative factor if the points lie outside the polygon. It sounds like your real question is: What should be the genetic representation of the points, and what genetic operators should you use to manipulate them. Is that more accurate?

Comment: Ya u r right. I have attached the code now. I am not able to make the points expand. The points are not changing because I have not written the code for the points to expand. I don't know how to include it in the fitness function.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you could do this. The easiest way would actually be with a GA, not a GP. In this case, you would have an array of integers broken into quads such that:

[funcx1, valx1, funcy1, valy1, funcx2, valx2, funcy2, valy2, ... , funcxn, valxn, funcyn, valyn]

Your fit function would take the modulus of the funcxi and get the corresponding function. Then, you would apply the number in valxi to that function to the corresponding x value. Given the points that are returned, you would calculate the area as you said and punish the individual if they go over the corresponding area (negative constant or factor by degree over).

Alternatively, if you have to use a GP for some reason, there are two main routes. If you want the code to be generic (i.e., you *apply* the same evolved chunk of code to each point; note: this is way harder), you would need more non-terminals (i.e., functions). I would probably add if-statements at minimum. Automatically defined functions (ADFs) would also be good and some kind of grouping function like progn from Lisp. Suffice to say, the GA method is way easier.

The other route is to use a more structured GP and add an assignment function instead.

GPnonterminals: +, -, *, /, ^, = (all vector functions)

GPterminals: point1, point2, ..., pointn, randompoint()

Using a Lispy structure, your code would look something like:

(* (= (= point2 (* randompoint() (= point2 randompoint()))) point1) randompoint())

Then, when you evaluate it, you would make all the assignments from the leafs to the root with overwriting of the lower points by higher ones. So, in the example above, point2 would get assigned as a random point (probably bad). The result would get multiplied by a random point and then overwrite the original assignment made to point2 with the result. That same result would get assigned to point1 and, finally, it would get multiplied by a randompoint. However, since there are no further assignments, the final value would just be discarded.

The reason why this is "more structured" is that you have to make sure assignment never occurs on anything other than a point. Grammar-based or grammar-guided GPs are particularly good at this. I'll refer you to this paper by Whigham (1995) that explains them:

http://sc.snu.ac.kr/courses/2007/fall/pg/aai/GP/whigham/whigham95grammaticallybased.pdf

If you use a GP, in either case, you are going to have to write some functions for list traversal for the format I described above. I also suggest using points and vector functions rather than x's and y's so that you have less terminals to keep track of (and your program trees will be smaller/process faster). Oh, and make sure the randompoint() function returns a specific point (i.e., make sure you evaluate it *before* you put it into the chromosome or the code will give inconsistent results -- very bad, that). And make the range of those possible points reasonable (i.e., don't go to 100 if you are in a space of 10 squared).

You have a bit of a way to go, but hopefully that points you in the right direction.